# Old game, probably electronic in movie Phantasm (1978)

Tags: gaming

At minute 40 in the movie Phantasm (1978) there is a strange game similar to a hexagon.
Is probably an electronic game, anyone know which game is this?

[image]

Comment: It's reminiscent of the [Simon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game)) which came out right around then.  I wonder if it's some competitor or knockoff.

Comment: Does someone actually play the game in the movie, or how do we know it's a game?  Could it just be a model spaceship or something like that?

Comment: Apparently there was even a hexagonal [Super Simon](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10152/super-simon/versions), though it came out years later and was a lot more colorful.

Comment: Yeah is really similar to simon, but can be also another object. The boy in the movie don't play with it.

Comment: I certainly didn't own something like that, and I don't remember wanting something like that. But I was a bit older than the character in 1978...

Comment: There was an octagonal knockoff of the Simon made by one of the Asian companies that sold many knockoff electronic games. But it was very colourful and didn't really resemble the object in the photo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a vintage desktop organizer like the one in [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/185199997767) eBay listing:

[image]

The vinyl covering the cardboard structure tended to split leading to retirement.

Comment: Nicely done; welcome to RC. Did you own one of those?

Comment: @knol Magic 8 Ball says: "Signs point to yes."  But I outgrew being organized.  In the 1970's keys were a thing.  In the '60s locking the front door on the way out was still optional.

Comment: Locking the front door on the way out is still optional, just be aware of the potential ramifications.